# Quarkus Using Reactive Hibernate: Parameter 'dataSource' may not be null

Tags: postgresql, quarkus, quarkus-reactive

I'm trying to switch from tranditional database accessing to reactive. In pom.xml i have added:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-reactive</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-reactive-pg-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

and in application.properties:

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql
quarkus.datasource.username=postgres
quarkus.datasource.password=pw
quarkus.datasource.reactive.url = postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
quarkus.datasource.jdbc = false
```

When i start Quarkus there is the error:

```
ERROR [io.qua.run.Application] (Quarkus Main Thread) Failed to start application (with profile dev): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter 'dataSource' may not be null
at org.wildfly.common.Assert.checkNotNullParamChecked(Assert.java:71)
at org.wildfly.common.Assert.checkNotNullParam(Assert.java:49)
at org.wildfly.security.auth.realm.jdbc.QueryConfiguration.<init>(QueryConfiguration.java:40)
at org.wildfly.security.auth.realm.jdbc.QueryBuilder.buildQuery(QueryBuilder.java:97)
at org.wildfly.security.auth.realm.jdbc.JdbcSecurityRealmBuilder.build(JdbcSecurityRealmBuilder.java:55)
at io.quarkus.elytron.security.jdbc.JdbcRecorder.createRealm(JdbcRecorder.java:42)
at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ElytronSecurityJdbcProcessor$configureJdbcRealmAuthConfig173765586.deploy_0(Unknown Source)
at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.ElytronSecurityJdbcProcessor$configureJdbcRealmAuthConfig173765586.deploy(Unknown Source)
at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.doStart(Unknown Source)
at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.start(Application.java:101)
at io.quarkus.runtime.ApplicationLifecycleManager.run(ApplicationLifecycleManager.java:110)
at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:70)
at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:43)
at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:123)
at io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.StartupActionImpl$1.run(StartupActionImpl.java:104)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the reasons of the problem and the approaches to fix that:

1. Did you set the `dataSource` parameter in the `ReactiveHibernate` constructor? If not, you can do that using the `@ConfigProperty` annotation
2. Check if the parameter is not null or has a valid value.

Comment: How can i set dataSource parameter in the ReactiveHibernate? I inject Mutiny.SessionFactory to query data. When i set `quarkus.datasource.jdbc = true`, there is error `Unsatisfied dependency for type org.hibernate.reactive.mutiny.Mutiny$SessionFactory and qualifiers [@Default]`

Comment: You need to add the dependency of the Mutiny$SessionFactory, seems it can't find it.